# jquery re-declare $(this)

Tags: jquery, variables, this

Is it not possible to re-declare `$.(this)` after a `$.click()` function? because none of these seems to work:

```
$(this) = $(this).find('span');
var $(this) = $(this).find('span');
```

Comment: `$(this)` is not a variable.  `$` is a variable, it's a function.  It returns a value (when a value is passed to it).

Comment: This is understanding basic javascript syntax and actually only has to do with jquery on the first glance. I'd say you have to dig into some literature.

Comment: thanks for your help folks, I'm actually learning javascript and the jQuery framework, little by little

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only declare `var foo`when `foo` is a legal *identifier*.

`$(this)` is the result of *calling* the function named `$` with argument `this` so it isn't legal in a declaration.

Nor should you overwrite `this` - it will cause much head scratching in the future!

If you want a local variable for storing the jQuery version of `this` then a common convention is:

```
var $this = $(this);
var $span = $this.find('span');
```

where the (perfectly legal, but sometimes frowned upon) `$` prefix allows you to remember that the variable is a jQuery object, and not a plain DOM element.

That convention also allows you to spot the wasteful (but common) error of doing:

```
var jqobj = $(myobj)
```

when `myobj` is *already* a jQuery object.

Comment: @w0rldart because by convention `$this` should only refer to `$(this)`, not any descendants of `this`. Sure, it works, but it'll confuse anyone else reading the code.  The `this` variable is kind of special, so you should treat `$this` the same way.

Comment: oh, I see... but that's not what I worry about right now, I worry to write as less code as possible :D

Comment: @w0rldart you should be worrying about writing _clear_, _maintainable_ code, not _less_ code.

Comment: oh, of course clear code is a basic principle also... but I really like the way I mentioned above. :)

Comment: @w0rldart I don't - if I was code reviewing that I'd be pulling the coder in for some re-education.  `var $span = $(this).find('span')` would be fine, though!  Just don't abuse `this` or `$this` !

Comment: Oh, I don't plan to abuse it @Alnitak. I just badly need it to fix a `$.click()` issue that had no other solution.

Answer (score 3):

The expression `$(this)` is not a variable declaration but instead is an expression.  If you want to redeclare something you need to store it in a variable

```
var saved = $(this);
saved = $(this).find('span');
```

The reason the final version works is because you are assigning it to an actual identifier.

Comment: @w0rldart it's the same solution but choosing the identifier `$this` instead of `saved`.  Either works, it's just a choice of which name you prefer

Comment: @JaredPar IMHO, `$this` should only _ever_ refer to `$(this)`, i.e. treat `$this` as if it was special as `this`.

Comment: Can i declare (var saved = $(this)) as global variable? I want to write this declaration in beginning and use in whole code instead of $(this). Can I do it? Meanwhile i cannot get it work. I do have and object, but i thing not exactly THIS.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('some').on('click', function() {
  var refrence = $(this);
  var span = refrence.find('span')
  // to override the $this you can use
  refrence = refrence.find('span');
});
```

Comment: seriously, don't change the meaning of `$this` once you've declared it - that would also cause confusion in the future.  Just use a new variable!